# angular directive to show a spinner in button

Tags: angular

I'm trying to write a directive to modify a button to show a spinner button while a server operation is in progress.

```
<button type="submit" waitingButton (click)="submit($event)">
 {{submitBtnText}}
</button>
```

So far, I've been able to show the spinner, but I don't know how to capture the result from the click event to switch it back to normal.

This is the directive:

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  OnInit,
  Renderer2,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { MatSpinner } from '@angular/material';


@Directive({
  selector: '[bcnWaitingButton]'
})
export class BCNWaitingButtonDirective implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef, 
    private renderer: Renderer2, 
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, 
    public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(e): void {
    // Create the spinner
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MatSpinner);
    const componentRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
    const spinner: MatSpinner = componentRef.instance;
    
    // Configure the spinner
    spinner.strokeWidth = 3;
    spinner.diameter = 24;

    // Set the button to disabled
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'disabled', 'true');
    
    // Apply new styles
    const span: ElementRef = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-button-wrapper');
    this.renderer.setStyle(span, 'display', 'flex');
    this.renderer.setStyle(span, 'align-items', 'center');
    this.renderer.setStyle(span, 'justify-content', 'center');
    this.renderer.setStyle(spinner._elementRef.nativeElement, 'margin-top', '0px');
    this.renderer.setStyle(spinner._elementRef.nativeElement, 'margin-left', '5px');

    // Append the spinner
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement.firstChild, spinner._elementRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to do that? Should I have an @Input with the submit callback so I can call it from the onClick function of the directive?

Comment: You should take a `@Input` in your directive to toggle between spinning and normal state. Eg- 
```<button type="submit" waitingButton [startLoading]="booleanVaraible"(click)="submit($event)">Click</button>```
`startLoading` will your `@Input` variable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to do it with a boolean variable, but I wanted to do it without adding extra code to the component, just using the return value of the submit function

Answer (score 10):

Here is a full working directive for replacing a Material button's text with a MatSpinner and then back to the text when the operation is complete. It utilizes parts of the first two answers:

```
import {
  ComponentFactoryResolver, Directive, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Renderer2, SimpleChanges, ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSpinner } from '@angular/material';

@Directive({
  selector: 'button[appShowSpinner]'
})
export class SpinnerButtonDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
  @Input('appShowSpinner') showSpinner: boolean;
  originalInnerText: string;
  spinner: MatSpinner;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Record the button's original text
    this.originalInnerText = this.el.nativeElement.innerText;

    // Set the button to maintain the same dimensions, even once we put the spinner inside.
    this.el.nativeElement.style.width = `${(this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).offsetWidth}px`;
    this.el.nativeElement.style.height = `${(this.el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).offsetHeight}px`;

    // Create the spinner
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MatSpinner);
    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
    this.spinner = componentRef.instance;

    // Configure the spinner
    this.spinner.strokeWidth = 3;
    this.spinner.diameter = 24;

    // Hide the spinner
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.spinner._elementRef.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');

    // Apply new styles to the button content's container
    const span = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-button-wrapper') as HTMLSpanElement;
    this.renderer.setStyle(span, 'display', 'flex');
    this.renderer.setStyle(span, 'align-items', 'center');
    this.renderer.setStyle(span, 'justify-content', 'center');
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (typeof(changes.showSpinner) === 'object' && !changes.showSpinner.isFirstChange()) {
      if (changes.showSpinner.currentValue === true) {
        // Clear the button's text
        const span = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-button-wrapper') as HTMLSpanElement;
        span.innerText = '';

        // Append the spinner
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement.firstChild, this.spinner._elementRef.nativeElement);

        // Show the spinner
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.spinner._elementRef.nativeElement, 'display', 'inherit');
      }

      if (changes.showSpinner.currentValue === false) {
        // Hide the spinner
        this.renderer.setStyle(this.spinner._elementRef.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');

        // Remove the spinner
        this.renderer.removeChild(this.el.nativeElement.firstChild, this.spinner._elementRef.nativeElement);

        const span = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.mat-button-wrapper') as HTMLSpanElement;
        span.innerText = this.originalInnerText;
      }

      this.el.nativeElement.disabled = changes.showSpinner.currentValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Using the directive:

```
<button [appShowSpinner]="isSaving" mat-raised-button>
  Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Remember to add `MatSpinner` to the `entryComponents` of the corresponding module, so it can be dynamically loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I just made an example that works ( although I cannot use material spinner in stackblitz because of a dependency error ) but this should guide you :

```
import { Directive, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[spinnerButton]'
})
export class SpinnerButtonDirective {
@Input('spinnerButton') isWaiting: boolean;
  originalInnerText: string;
  constructor( private el: ElementRef ) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    // Save the original button text so I can restore it when waiting ends
    this.originalInnerText = this.el.nativeElement.innerText;
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.isWaiting) {
      this.el.nativeElement.innerText = 'waiting...';
    } else {
      if (this.el.nativeElement.innerText == 'waiting...') {
        this.el.nativeElement.innerText = this.originalInnerText;
      }
    }
    this.el.nativeElement.disabled = this.isWaiting;
  }
}
```

In your html,

```
<button (click)="getData()" [spinnerButton]="isWaiting">Get Data</button>
```

The only thing you have to do then, is set isWaiting to true or false in your code ( normally in getData() function )

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rb5vmu